# Why is the Angular http get response body wrapped in an array of length 1?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

My Angular app is making an API call and expecting to get back a single JSON object, but the body is a JSON array of length 1 with that single JSON object.  The object is correct, but it should not be wrapped in an array.  I've been banging my head against a wall long enough, so hopefully one of you smart folks can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
const response = await firstValueFrom(this.http.get<IWebsite>("/api/website/0", {observe: 'response', responseType: 'json'}));
console.log(response.body);
```

proxy.conf.js

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/api",
        ],
        target: "https://localhost:7203",
        secure: false
    }
];
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

If I hit the API directly (ASP.NET Core Web API), I get back the single JSON object as expected.  This works whether I'm using Postman, in a browser, or in the same Angular application (i.e., https://localhost:7203/api/website/0).

I'm using angular 16.1.3 with node v18.16.1 and TypeScript 5.1.6.

**Edit:** in response to 1st comment

console.log output
[image]

dev tools Network Response

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "createdDate": "2023-07-09T18:56:52.1892047Z",
        "updatedDate": "2023-07-10T03:21:02.3061564Z",
        "name": "Reddit",
        "scheme": "https",
        "subdomain": null,
        "domain": "reddit.com",
        "port": null,
        "fileSystemPath": "P:\\Web\\reddit"
    }
]
```

Postman Response

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "createdDate": "2023-07-09T18:56:52.1892047Z",
    "updatedDate": "2023-07-10T03:21:02.3061564Z",
    "name": "Reddit",
    "scheme": "https",
    "subdomain": null,
    "domain": "reddit.com",
    "port": null,
    "fileSystemPath": "P:\\Web\\reddit"
}
```

**Edit:** in response to 2nd comment

I tried both of these and got the same result:

```
this.http.get<IWebsite>("/api/website/0").subscribe(response => console.log(response));

fetch("/api/website/0")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

This gave me the expected result, though:

```
this.http.get<IWebsite>("https://localhost:7203/api/website/0").subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

Comment: This does not seem possible. can you paste the exact output of your `console.log` statement in comparison to your Postman output?

Comment: by defect httpClient return a json object, so you can try remove the `{observe: 'response', responseType: 'json'}`. Futhermore, I feel the your function `firstValueFrom` it's who return an array, not the httpClient.get

Comment: This was stupid user error on my part.